# Is this cryptographically secure?

Tags: cryptography

I am making a chat program for fun, and I decided to add in encryption. However, I am new to this, so what I was wondering is, is this cryptographically secure, and is this a good way to do things?

**This is logging in:**

**Start:**

Client sends username

*If the user exists, the server sends the stored salt for the user*

The client then sends SHA-2 hashed (Salt + Plaintext password)

*The server compares it to the stored hashed result of the salt +  the password, and if it’s the same then the user has logged in sucessfully, and from there on the encryption is AES.*

**End**

Any faults? I don’t think there is, but I’d hate to go along and make the program only to be told that the encryption doesn't work! Also, anyone got any good links to further reading on cryptography?

Comment: Is this running on top of SSL? Are you authenticating the server somehow? Without having both of these, this is obviously insecure.

Comment: If you send a *nonce* with the salt, and have the client respond with the HMAC of the hashed password + salt, then you can at least avoid replay attacks.

Comment: Not really a crypto issue, but *If the user exists, the server sends...* means i can assemble a list of valid usernames without even bothering to try a password.  I'd recommend if you do this at all, the server pretend nonexistent users are valid and send a dummy salt.

Comment: @DietrichEpp can you avoid replay attacks that way? How secret is this HMAC key when the client has to have it?

Comment: @jbtule: The key is a nonce, not a secret.  Replay attacks are prevented because the hash will be different each time.

Comment: @jbtule: I guess HMAC is not necessary here, an ordinary cryptographic hash function should be fine.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Sorry, I misconstrued, that makes sense.

Comment: The question is incorrect. "Is this cryptographically secure?" - from what it is secured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't secure against attacks on your database/servers, and actually seems to defeat the purpose of using salted hashes.  If the client sends back a salted hash in place of their password, then that is essentially the same as their password.

If an attacker compromises your database, they don't have to brute force anyone's password to log in, they just use the salted hash and they can be anyone they want to be.

If you are using SSL, you can send the plaintext password over the encrypted wire, and hash at the server.  Then an attacker has to brute force the hash or attack the SSL channel.

also, use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt as your password hashing algorithm, instead of SHA-2.  You want something that resists brute force attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the transmission of your hash is encrypted with SSL, since if the hash is compromised your user account is compromised.

As mentioned in the comment by CodesInChaos, verifying the server's public key in SSL is **important** and **necessary**.

Comment: And make sure to verify the server's public key/certificate in SSL. Either by linking to a trusted root certificate, or by hardcoding the fingerprint.

Comment: But would the hash be required to be encrypted with SSL if it is changed the second the user logs in (Or attempts to)? Because surely then, although someone could have gotten hold of the hash, it would be out of date?

Comment: @Flyingfirepig I'm going under the assumption that the server doesn't know the clear text password (rightly so), thus wouldn't be able to change the salt anyway, but yes even if you could change the salt you'd still need ssl to make sure you don't have a man in the middle.

Comment: @Flyingfirepig think of it this way, when you ask "is this secure?", and you use crypto primitives you actually have created a considerably long rope to hang yourself with, if you us a high level construct like SSL its a much much shorter rope, don't resist it.

Comment: Okay, I see, so should I use SSL for the login procedure _and_ sending messages and do away with AES encryption, or should I just use SSL for logging in?

Comment: @Flyingfirepig go for the "short rope", SSL for both.

Comment: If you're going to go to the trouble of spooling up an SSL/TLS link why not just use SSL/TLS, which is a standard that is well known and vetted, instead of cooking up your own?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no and why would chance it anyways?" and the long answer is way too long and involved. There are too many variables that are unknown for us to give a good answer: Is the link betweent he client and the server encrypted? Do you verify the identity of the server that you are connecting to? Etc.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't reinvent the wheel and you should avoid home-brewed cryptograpy. For passwords, considering using [scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) and be happy.

If you want to verify the password the user is entering, you may also want to consider implementing a challenge-response authentication system or at least implement some protection against replay attacks. Your current solution is completely insecure, in that it makes the salted hash *itself* the password. An attacker who grabs that can login to the account without ever knowing the password.

Again, don't invent your own stuff. Use protocols that have been designed and validated by cryptographers and the community at large. Wikipedia is a good place to start your research. The book "Applied Cryptography" by Bruce Schneier is a *great* resource and every software developer should have it in their library.

Comment: I would probably go with the new edition "Cryptography Engineering" instead of Applied Cryptography.

Comment: It would be nice if whoever downvoted this explained their reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

As long as this exchange is over SSL, it should be fine. Also, if you're set on using a member of the SHA-2 family, use SHA-512. Anything less is unacceptable today.

The protocol you describe is basically the standard user/pass website login + a salt-exchange.

Better though would be to do the salting and SHA hashing on the server. Let the user transmit their password in plain-text over SSL and never reveal the salt.

[JChatd](http://code.google.com/p/jchatd/) is an example peer-to-peer chat client over SSL.

Comment: Even if it's over SSL, it may not be fine. What if the SSL implementation of the client doesn't validate the identity of the server that is connecting? You connect to a fake server who gives you a salt for which the attakcer has rainbow tables and *boom*. There is a reason why cryptography is difficult and tricky and why even experts call it a dark art.

Comment: Sounds like a broken SSL implementation (though that's not unheard of). And a rainbow table of salt+hash would be far less practical than a rainbow table of passwords (assuming a high-entropy salt generator). Add strong encryption with a large key size and it becomes less practical. A very dark art indeed, but not one without forerunners.

Comment: You are missing my point. No SSL implementation that I know of validates the identity of the server as part of the implementation proper - because it doesn't know the identity of the server. The programmer integrating SSL must do that and a table of salted-hashes for a particular salt is trivial to build.

Comment: Now, if the SSL implementation of the client doesn't validate the server identity, an attacker can inject a fake server, complete an SSL handshake and tell the client software "your salt is <x>. What's the salted-pass?" with <x> being whatever the salt the attacker *already* has a rainbow table for. The client doesn't know what the salt is supposed to be. It accepts whatever the server tells it and calculates the salted hash with the salt the attacker gave it in order to respond. Once it does the attacker can check his rainbow table trivially.

Comment: @Nik: What are those "hey, this key fingerprint isn't what i was expecting!" messages that openssh and putty both output, if they're not checking the server's public key against a list of known hosts and their key fingerprints?

Comment: @CHao: SSH isn't SSL. But even if putty and OpenSSH were SSL based, they would be *specific* implementations, probably utilizing a library. OpenSSL for example allows those who use the library to query the identity of the remote server (i.e. the details of the certificate the server uses) but can't do anything more than that. OpenSSL doesn't really know that you meant to connect to mykewlchat.com and not mycoolchat.com. All it knows is that whatever you connected to presented a certificate for which it had a corresponding private key and completed the SSL handshake successfully.

Comment: Heh.  All this time i thought SSH was based on SSL.  Go me.  :P

Answer (score 0):

the client could send, username and sha(password) , and the server could make the conversions and comparations, and the server not send the a salt for the user

here is agood course about cryptography

```
https://class.coursera.org/crypto/class/index
```

Comment: I'm sorry but are you suggesting that the client should send the password to the server in plaintext? Especially over what might be an unencrypted link!? *Why* would you suggest this?

Comment: Hashing username+password on the client is sound in principle (see SRP), but the OP's construction probably isn't. If done correctly in the context of a client(not browser) SRP is stronger than sending username+password to the server. So I disagree with your answer.

Comment: @NikBougalis The encrypted link(SSL) is required anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you describe

> If the user exists, the server sends the stored salt for the user

What is being send here? The password's hash?
If yes then there is no security. The idea is that the user provides the password to the client and the client sends the encrypted hash to the server for comparison.If there is a match the user has been authenticated

Comment: All you've achieved is to make salted-hashed password into the password itself. The attacker doesn't care if the token needed to authenticate is the raw password "password123" or the salted hashed version: "57893131-nkg48923nv8939563". All they want is what they need to send to the server to authenticate.

Comment: @NikBougalis:I don't follow you.This is the standard approach for any user/password login.Additionally it will be send over ssl.Are you suggesting some specific protocol?

Comment: if the server sends the user the salt and the client then replies back with the salted-hash of the password, then the salted hash of the password has effectively become the password. This *could* work if you are doing this over an SSL link, but does it? And even if it does, why use it when there are *better* approaches? This is what challenge-response authentication protocols were designed for.

Comment: @NikBougalis:But I don't mention in the answer that the server should send the user the salt.I mention not to do it. Just the sending of the password's hash over SSL is ok

Comment: it *may* be OK. Again, if all the client has to send is the *same* token (whether it's the plaintext password, or some hashed version of the password) the fact is that the token the attacker needs to authenticate is static and available. SSL (provided it's implemented properly) would make that a non-issue, but can you assume that there's SSL and a proper implementation?

Comment: @NikBougalis:I don't get what is your point.If the password is weak or the user reveals there is also an issue.Are you suggesting some other protocol to the OP that is not user-name/password based?